# Translate pipe with parameters

Tags: angular, angular-translate

I'm using translate pipe. I have a string, that include website of my company and I shouldn't translate it. So I use parameters. But website should be a link(tag ). How can I do it?

```
<p class="al-privacy-policy-text">{{"PRIVACY_POLICY_PAGE.INTRODUCTION_TEXT" | translate: ({website: 'https://www.title.com/'})}}</p>
```

Now https://www.title.com is a simply text.

> "PRIVACY_POLICY_PAGE.INTRODUCTION_TEXT": " ...when using our website {{website}}..."

Comment: What is the expected output? Do you want an anchor element where the title is a link or do you want something else?

Comment: I want that 'https://tittle.com' was a link and I can go to it in the "PRIVACY_POLICY_PAGE.INTRODUCTION_TEXT"  block

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change the content of `PRIVACY_POLICY_PAGE.INTRODUCTION_TEXT` to use an anchor tag for the website placeholder. Then use `innerHtml` to allow html content so it will not be sanitized.

```
<p class="al-privacy-policy-text" [innerHTML]="'PRIVACY_POLICY_PAGE.INTRODUCTION_TEXT' | translate: ({website: 'https://www.title.com/'})"></p>
```

See also [Sanitization and security contexts](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-and-security-contexts) and [How to include html tags in your translation strings](https://github.com/ngx-translate/core/issues/145)